# python list variables in works by pattern (Python equivalent of R ls(pattern="namepattern")

Tags: python

What is the python command to list all variables existing in the current worskpace that match a certain pattern? For example, list all existing variables/objects in the workspace that start with "ABC"

Comment: are you looking for all variables with names that start with "ABC" or all variables with values that start with "ABC".

Comment: both [IGNORExxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]

Answer (score 2):

You can create a copy of the local varibals by calling `copy` on `locals()` (or `globals()` alternatively) to search through a key value pair of variable names and values and then do what you want with the resulting dictionary

```
import copy
ABCD = 'woof' # create the name and value of our var
local_dict = copy.copy(locals()) # create a shallow copy of all local variables, you don't want to iterate through a constantly changing dict
for name, value in d.items():
    if name.startswith('ABC'):
         print(name, value)
```

Calling `help(locals)` gives you this as an explantion:

```
locals()
    Return a dictionary containing the current scope's local variables.

    NOTE: Whether or not updates to this dictionary will affect name lookups in
    the local scope and vice-versa is *implementation dependent* and not
    covered by any backwards compatibility guarantees.
```

EDIT:

here is a shorter oneliner for just the name:
 `[name for name in copy.copy(locals().keys()) if name.startswith('ABC')]`

Comment: Can you elaborate why you think you should copy the data? Also, why copy *everything* if you can just copy the names?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That will help. Even though I find it astonishing that you have to write a custom function for something so simple and straightforward. An improvement opportunity for python I guess

Comment: @NilsWerner right you are, I assumed the user wanted to do something with the values as well.

Answer (score 2):

### Searching through variables

In R, `ls(pattern=...)` does two things:

1. If called inside a function, it searches through the locals of that function.
2. If called from the top level, it searches through the workspace (all global) variables

so

```
alpha <- 1.
animal <- "dog"
tool <- "wrench"

ls(pattern="^a.*")
# "alpha"  "animal"

myfunction <- function(){
    value <- 1
    ls(pattern="value")
}

myfunction()
# "value"
```

both cases can be done in Python by searching through `locals()`:

```
import re

alpha = 1.
animal = "dog"
tool = "wrench"

[x for x in locals() if re.match('^a.*', x)]
# ['alpha', 'animal']

def function():
    value = 1
    print([x for x in locals() if re.match('value', x)])

function()
# ['value']
```

### Writing an `ls(...)` function

Unfortunately, you cannot implement a function like `ls()` in Python that searches through `locals()` because as soon as you enter that function, the current scope is lost and you get the variables local to `ls()`:

```
def ls(pattern='.*'):
    return [x for x in locals() if re.match(pattern, x)]

def function():
    value = 1
    print(ls())

function()
# ['pattern']    <- This is actually in scope of `ls()`, not of `function()`

ls()
# ['pattern']    <- This is actually in scope of `ls()`, not in global scope
```

to achieve this, you need to explicitly search through all variables that are **local to the parent frame**. This can be done using the `inspect` module:

```
import inspect

def ls(pattern='.*'):
    return [x for x in inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals if re.match(pattern, x)]

def function():
    value = 1
    print(ls())

function()
# ['value']    <- This is in scope of `function()`

ls()
# ['ls', 'function', ...]    <- This is in global scope
```